# Remove footer on title page

Tags: page-numbering, footer

Apologies if this question has been answered already . I am struggling to remove the page number from the footer on the title page, I am happy for the footer to be removed completey from the title page or for the page number to be removed from that page and for the counter to begin on the page after.

Thank you in advance for your help

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{grffile} %Stops the file name of figures appearing
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\officialeuro}{%
  \ifmmode\expandafter\text\fi
  {\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{eurosym}\selectfont e}}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\title{Business Plan}
\author{}
\date{}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{algorithmic}
 \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\textheight=23cm
\textwidth=16cm
\topmargin=-1cm
\oddsidemargin=0cm
\parindent=0mm
\pretolerance=2000
\tolerance=3000

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries %glossaries

\backgroundsetup{
  scale=1,
  color=black,
  opacity=1,
  angle=0,
  position=current page.south,
  vshift=60pt,
  contents={%
  \small\sffamily%
  \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
  \parbox[b]{.6\textwidth}{%
    Page \thepage\ of   \pageref{LastPage}}\hfill
  \parbox[b]{.4\textwidth}{%
    \raggedleft xxxx, xxxx \\ xxxx, xxxx}\      \textcolor{red}{\rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}}\      \url{www.xxxx.com}
  \end{minipage}\hspace{.02\textwidth}%
  \begin{minipage}{.18\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=70pt,keepaspectratio]{iPhone app}
  \end{minipage}%
  }
}

\tcbset{rawlings/.style={width=\textwidth,colback={white},colbacktitle=SkyBlue,coltitle=black,colupper=black}}

% A separate box with a separate list type named rawlings
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,list inside=rawlings]{rawlingsbox}[1][]{rawlings,#1}%

\newcommand{\listofrawlings}{%
  \tcblistof[\chapter*]{rawlings}{List of Rawlings Boxes}
}



\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{plain}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth]{iPhone app}\par\vspace{1cm}


    \vfill

% Bottom of the page
    {\large \today\par}
\end{titlepage}

\clearpage

\begin{rawlingsbox}[width=\textwidth,colback={white},title={\textbf{The Mission}},colbacktitle=red,coltitle=black,colupper=black]   
The mission statement for this plan is \textbf{to inspire ambition and purpose through cricket by}:
\begin{itemize}
\item Promoting cricket for a younger target audience
\item Producing successful, competitive and entertaining cricket
\end{itemize}

The objectives for the update of the english T20 system in this plan are:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item To compete with the other growing T20 leagues across the world
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Increase  television coverage across the world through the appeal of the tournament to a wider audience
    \end{itemize}
    \item Improve fan attendance and engagement
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Continue to increase the number of spectators at each T20 Blast match
        \item Change the schedule of the T20 season to coincide with the school summer holidays
        \item Attract more 'International Stars' to the english game
    \end{itemize}
    \item Support the counties to become more financially independent
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Generate larger incomes for the county clubs
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Membership system
            \item Fan attendance
            \item Television revenues
        \end{itemize}
        \item Reduce the high cost to income ratio of costs associated with the large number of matches 
    \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{rawlingsbox}    
\clearpage

\begin{rawlingsbox} [width=\textwidth,colback={white},colbacktitle=red,coltitle=black,colupper=black,title={\textbf{Executive Summary}}]
\end{rawlingsbox}  

\clearpage
\listofrawlings

\clearpage
\listoffigures

\listoftables

\clearpage

\begin{rawlingsbox}[width=\textwidth,colback={white},colbacktitle=red,coltitle=black,colupper=black,title={\textbf{Executive Summary}},title={\textbf{Introduction}}]   
\end{rawlingsbox}  

\begin{rawlingsbox}[width=\textwidth,colback={white},colbacktitle=red,coltitle=black,colupper=black,title={\textbf{Executive Summary}},title={\textbf{Strategic Audit}}]   
\end{rawlingsbox}  

\begin{rawlingsbox}[width=\textwidth,colback={white},colbacktitle=red,coltitle=black,colupper=black,title={\textbf{Executive Summary}},title={\textbf{Generating Strategic Options}}]   
\end{rawlingsbox}  

\begin{rawlingsbox}[width=\textwidth,colback={white},colbacktitle=red,coltitle=black,colupper=black,title={\textbf{Executive Summary}},title={\textbf{Conclusions}}]  
\end{rawlingsbox}  

\begin{rawlingsbox}[width=\textwidth,colback={white},colbacktitle=red,coltitle=black,colupper=black,title={\textbf{Executive Summary}},title={\textbf{Recommendations}}]   
\end{rawlingsbox}  

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\thispagestyle{plain}`  is setting the footer. Remove it.

Comment: Replace `\thispagestyle{plain}` with   `\thispagestyle{empty}`.

Comment: Neither of those work unfortunately

Comment: @DanielRawlings, it works, however had to be in right place -- after `\begin{titlepage}`, i.e. `\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\pagestyle{empty}
    \centering`. Off-topic: some packages you load twice ...

Comment: @zarko , that is where I put it :/ however, still the footer remains :(

Comment: You are also adding footer material through the background. Add `\NoBgThispage` before titlepage if you want to suppress it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you are an absolute star! Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Apart from the issue with the `\thispagestyle{empty}`: There's content loaded with `\includegraphics` which isn't available to us, and even worse: the graphics file has spaces in the file name :-(